# How to add virtual fields to query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

To improve performance, I have written the following:

```
a = Address.joins(:vacancies).select('"addresses"."city", COUNT (*) AS total_count').group('"addresses"."city"').order('total_count DESC')
```

instead of:

```
a = Address.all.keep_if{ |a| a.vacancies.all_active.size > 0 }.uniq{ |a| a.city }.map{ |a| [a.city, a.vacancies.all_active.size] }.sort{ |aa, ab| aa[1] <=> ab[1] }.reverse
```

However, the `total_count` field doesn't show up in the result. If I run the query in sqlite it DOES show up. I added a virtual attribute to the Address model but this doesn't help. How to fix this?

In addition, this is my Rails console output:

```
1.9.3p194 :010 > a = Address.joins(:vacancies).select("addresses.city, count(*) as total_count").group("addresses.city").order("total_count DESC")
  Address Load (3.9ms)  SELECT addresses.city, count(*) as total_count FROM "addresses" INNER JOIN "vacancies" ON "vacancies"."address_id" = "addresses"."id" GROUP BY addresses.city ORDER BY total_count DESC
 => [#<Address city: "Amsterdam">, #<Address city: "Rotterdam">, #<Address city: "Utrecht">, #<Address city: "Den haag">, #<Address city: "Delft">, #<Address city: "Hilversum">, #<Address city: "Amstelveen">, #<Address city: "Rijswijk">, #<Address city: "Breda">, #<Address city: "Zwolle">, #<Address city: "Tilburg">, #<Address city: "Amersfoort">, #<Address city: "Amsterdam centrum">, #<Address city: "Eindhoven">, #<Address city: "Next nature netwerk, amsterdam">, #<Address city: "Almere">, #<Address city: "Ameide">, #<Address city: "Arnhem">, #<Address city: "Baarlo">, #<Address city: "Capelle a/d ijssel">, #<Address city: "De lier">, #<Address city: "Leiden">, #<Address city: "Reigerstraat 16, breda">, #<Address city: "Rottedam">, #<Address city: "'s-hertogenbosch ">, #<Address city: "Alkmaar">, #<Address city: "Alphen aan den rijn">, #<Address city: "Amsterdam singel 137">, #<Address city: "Amsterdam, keizergracht">, #<Address city: "Barendrecht">, #<Address city: "Den haag e.o.">, #<Address city: "Deventer">, #<Address city: "Dordrecht">, #<Address city: "Groningen">, #<Address city: "Gummo, amsterdam">, #<Address city: "Hillversum">, #<Address city: "Houten">, #<Address city: "Lisse">, #<Address city: "Moti, breda">, #<Address city: "Nijmegen">, #<Address city: "Rotterdam ">, #<Address city: "Tuil (waardenburg)">, #<Address city: "Zaltbommel">] 
1.9.3p194 :011 > a.first.total_count
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :012 > a.first.to_json
 => "{\"city\":\"Amsterdam\",\"total_count\":null}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, remove the virtual attribute (I assume you mean you've got `attr_accessor :total_count` in your model).

Active Record's `inspect` method (which is what generates the output in the console) is hard wired to only display information about attrbutes it expects, i.e. the ones that correspond to actual columns on the table. Attributes that only exist because you added something to the select clause won't show up. They are still there -  you could do

```
a.first.total_count
```

or

```
a.first.attributes
```

to see it. In your console session `a.first.total_count` doesn't work because your `attr_accessor` is shadowing the database attribute.

The `to_json` method is similar in that by default it serialises the attributes it knows about. You can include `total_count` in your output by doing

```
a.to_json(:methods => [:total_count])
```

Comment: I've removed total_count from attr_accessible, however I still can't access the total count through `a.first.total_count`. What DOES work is `a.first.attributes['total_count']`. Your suggestion to use `to_json` returns a json object where all total_count attributes are nill though.

Comment: from attr_accessible or attr_accessor/attr_reader/attr_writer ? It's the second lot that are bad in this context.

Answer (score 2):

your query:

```
@result = Address.joins(:vacancies).select("addresses.city, count(*) as total_count").group("addresses.city").order("total_count DESC")
```

total count of the first element:

```
@result.first.total_count
```

If you can't see the total_count attribute in the console

```
@result.first.to_json
```

will show you all attributes.

**tip:** I think you are using too many quotation marks and you don't need to prefix attributes with table names if attribute exists in only one table. Joins doesn't improve performance. If you want performance improvement, take a look at [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: I think in this case there will be some performance improvement, see edit. Nevertheless I find your suggestions very helpful. Results still aren't what I expect them to be, but I need to play with it a bit more before I can tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Please see additional edits, I've added the console output to illustrate what's happening.